# How to create signed increments in Laravel's Schema?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following in my migration file:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('Users', function($table)
   {
      $table->engine='InnoDB';
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('name', 255);
   });
}
```

So far the whole application used `signed` ids, and I don't want to break this so how can I make them `signed`? I know that the default value is `unsigned` and that there is a `->unsigned()` modifier (that I don't understand whats is for if this is the default value) but from this I supposed there is a `->signed()` too, but there isn't. The following code runs without errors but the id is still unsigned when I watch it in phpMyAdmin:

```
Schema::create('Users', function($table)
{
   $table->engine='InnoDB';
   $table->increments('id')->signed();
   $table->string('name', 255);
});
```

I searched the [official](http://laravel.com/docs/schema) and a [non official](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-migrations-managing-databases/) documentation but none of them mentioned anything about this. So how can I make it `signed`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An integer column set to auto-increment should do just the trick if you also want it signed.

```
$table->integer('id', true);
```

From: framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php

```
/**
 * Create a new integer column on the table.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
 * @param  bool  $unsigned
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
{
  return $this->addColumn('integer', $column, compact('autoIncrement', 'unsigned'));
}
```